# virtual box to other virtual box connectivity issue

Tags: troubleshooting

I am creating a cluster setup on virtual boxes. I have Ubuntu 14.4 installed in all systems. Both the systems are having virtual box installed.

I have changed the ip-address to static on both virtual boxes. In the virtual box setting i have made bridge network on the virtual box default setting.

Now i am able to ping local machine from the virtual box on which it is installed. But not getting connection with the other machine or other machine's virtual box.

[image]

Help please..

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about VM configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a home network.

Answer (score 2):

Did you change the mac addresses for the networks cards for those two virtual box machines? I mean... are those addresses different? That may cause problems.
Bridge connection is the same as direct connection to the network.

Is there a switch in between? How do you connect those two computers?
If there's a switch be sure that there's no security policy that allows only 1 mac address on a port. That can also be the case.

Regards